# OBJ Loader IndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, 3d, lwjgl, 3d-model

Im writing a 3D Engine and my OBJ LoaderClass seems to have problems with more complex Models.

Im getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException and i cant figure out why.
The value of the ArrayList textures on the index 3522 seems to cause this exception, but why?

Here is my OBJ Loader Class

```
        package graphics.renderEngine;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.joml.Vector2f;
    import org.joml.Vector3f;

    import graphics.models.RawModel;

    public class OBJLoader 
    {

        public static RawModel loadObjModel(String fileName, Loader loader)
        {
            FileReader fr = null;
            try 
            {
                fr = new FileReader(new File("Ressources/Models/"+fileName+".obj"));
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                System.err.println("Could not load File!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            List<Vector3f> vertices = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
            List<Vector2f> textures = new ArrayList<Vector2f>();
            List<Vector3f> normals = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
            List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            float[] verticesArray = null;
            float[] normalsArray = null;
            float[] texturesArray = null;
            int[] indicesArray = null;

            try
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    line = reader.readLine();
                    String[] currentLine = line.split(" ");
                    if(line.startsWith("v "))
                    {
                        Vector3f vertex = new Vector3f(Float.parseFloat(currentLine[1]),Float.parseFloat(currentLine[2]), Float.parseFloat(currentLine[3]));
                        vertices.add(vertex);
                    }
                    else if(line.startsWith("vt "))
                    {
                        Vector2f texture = new Vector2f(Float.parseFloat(currentLine[1]), Float.parseFloat(currentLine[2]));
                        textures.add(texture);
                    }
                    else if(line.startsWith("vn "))
                    {
                        Vector3f normal = new Vector3f(Float.parseFloat(currentLine[1]),Float.parseFloat(currentLine[2]), Float.parseFloat(currentLine[3]));
                        normals.add(normal);
                    }
                    else if(line.startsWith("f "))
                    {
                        texturesArray = new float[vertices.size()*2];
                        normalsArray = new float[vertices.size()*3];
                        break;
                    }
                }

                while(line != null)
                {
                    if(!line.startsWith("f "))
                    {
                        line = reader.readLine();
                        continue;
                    }
                    String[] currentLine = line.split(" ");
                    String[] vertex1 = currentLine[1].split("/");
                    String[] vertex2 = currentLine[2].split("/");
                    String[] vertex3 = currentLine[3].split("/");

                    processVertex(vertex1, indices, textures, normals, texturesArray, normalsArray);
                    processVertex(vertex2, indices, textures, normals, texturesArray, normalsArray);
                    processVertex(vertex3, indices, textures, normals, texturesArray, normalsArray);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
                reader.close();

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            verticesArray = new float[vertices.size()*3];
            indicesArray = new int[indices.size()];

            int vertexPointer = 0;
            for (Vector3f vertex:vertices)
            {
                verticesArray[vertexPointer++] = vertex.x;
                verticesArray[vertexPointer++] = vertex.y;
                verticesArray[vertexPointer++] = vertex.z;
            }

            for(int i=0;i<indices.size();i++)
            {
                indicesArray[i] = indices.get(i);

            }
            return 
                    loader.loadToVAO
                    (verticesArray, 
                            texturesArray, 
                            normalsArray,
                            indicesArray);

        }

        private static void processVertex(String[] vertexData, List<Integer> indices, List<Vector2f> textures, List<Vector3f> normals, float[] textureArray, float[] normalsArray)
        {
            System.out.println(textures.get(3522));
            int currentvertexPointer = Integer.parseInt(vertexData[0]) -1;
            indices.add(currentvertexPointer);
            Vector2f currentTex = textures.get(Integer.parseInt(vertexData[1])-1);
            textureArray[currentvertexPointer*2] = currentTex.x;
            textureArray[currentvertexPointer*2+1] = 1 - currentTex.y;
            Vector3f currentNorm = normals.get(Integer.parseInt(vertexData[2])-1);
            normalsArray[currentvertexPointer*3] = currentNorm.x;
            normalsArray[currentvertexPointer*3+1] = currentNorm.y;
            normalsArray[currentvertexPointer*3+2] = currentNorm.z;
        }
 }
```

[This is the OBJFile of the Model im trying to load](http://www.spytrycer.de/obj.txt)

When i read out the texture values everytime via:

```
System.out.println(textures.get(Integer.parseInt(vertexData[1])-1));
```

The last Vectors i get before the Exceptions are:

```
( 4.260E-1  1.275E-1)
( 4.650E-1  1.664E-1)
( 4.706E-1  1.621E-1)
( 4.650E-1  1.664E-1)
( 4.925E-1  2.140E-1)
( 1.340E-1  8.170E-2)
( 1.947E-1  4.650E-2)
( 1.902E-1  3.560E-2)
```

Which after looking at the OBJ FIle, except for the last two, i cant find in sequence.

Here is the Exception im getting

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3522, Size: 3522
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at graphics.renderEngine.OBJLoader.processVertex(OBJLoader.java:122)
    at graphics.renderEngine.OBJLoader.loadObjModel(OBJLoader.java:82)
    at main.Main.init(Main.java:150)
    at main.Main.<init>(Main.java:82)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:75)
```

Im just puzzled, i have no idea why i get this exception, thanks in advance for any clue

Comment: If interested, [here](https://github.com/java-graphics/assimp) we have a jvm port of assimp, obj is already supported

Answer (score 1):

The size of the list is 3522 and which has index values in the range of 0 to 3521. But you are trying to use the non existent index that is 3522 to access the element in the list, hence the exception. You need to have the condition to check that index is less than size before accessing the list element.

Comment: Like this: 
  if(textures.size() > Integer.parseInt(vertexData[1])-1)
  {
   currentTex = textures.get(Integer.parseInt(vertexData[1])-1);
  }  ?

Comment: I tried this, then i got multiple other OutOfBounds Exceptions from ALL the following Arrays. Assuming i should do that to all of these exceptions then, i did but ended up with an not even half loaded Model

Comment: Ok, but the logic should make sure that you are accessing elements within the size limit.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is that you stop reading 'v', 'vt' and 'vn' declarations once you see the first 'f' (face) declaration. You cannot do this, because the Wavefront OBJ specification does not state that 'v*' declarations need to come before 'f' declarations. And in fact, in your example file they are intermingled.
That means, when you stop reading the 'v*' declarations in your first loop, you will eventually find 'f' declarations that reference other 'v*' declarations which you did not read, hence you'll get the IndexOutOfBounds exception.
You should restructure your loops so that reading 'v*' as well as 'f' declarations is possible at any time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are following the tutorial of https://www.youtube.com/user/ThinMatrix

The tutorial is fine; it works perfectly. (I have used it before)

## The Problem

The issue is that his OBJLoader is specific to the format of OBJ file he chose and is not an "all-purpose" OBJ-loader.

His format is the following:
v/vt/vn/f/EOF

Whereas your is more like:
v/vt/vn/f/v/vt/vn/f/.../EOF

The code that you have posted assumes that after it finds the first line with 'f', there will be no more vertex data and there will only be face data afterwards.

Therefore, the code isn't receiving all of the vertex data so when you try to index into that data, it isn't there.

## The Fix

There are two possible solutions to this:

1. Re-configure your code to work in a more general sense by allowing it to accept all of the data from the file and then load it up into buffers.
2. Re-structure your OBJ file so that it lies correctly within the format outlined by ThinMatrix. The easiest way is probably to copy/paste although you could create a program that does this for you.

I'm guessing that since you are following a tutorial on the subject, you don't have much experience with it and the easiest path for you will be solution number 2.

Answer (score 0):

check
return loader.loadToVAO(verticesArray,textureArray,indicesArray);

here are minor spelling mistake see the spelling of textureArray
and you deffined the texturesArray there is an s .

Comment: Please consider formatting your code before answering. Also, provide with a comment only, if a comment can do the job, instead of posting an answer

See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)